# How to select rows from two tables where both have the same value in the same field?

Tags: java, mysql, ms-access

I have two tables that have the same column names.

There is a field called `Call_Status` in both tables.

I want to retrieve the records having `Call_Status="Open"` from both tables. i.e. I want a query that can retrieve all the records of `table1` having `call_Status="Open"` & then from `table2` having `call_Status="Open"`

I have no idea how to do this and would appreciate some guidance

Comment: Your question was very hard to read - I have edited it to make it more useful for others in the future.  Please make sure you have a look at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best answers.  You've also tagged it both `mysql` and `ms-access`. In this case, it probably doesn't matter which database you are using, but usually it's pretty unlikely that you'll be using ***both*** `mysql` and `ms-access`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get all the matching rows from the first table and all the matching rows from the second table (as opposed to joining rows together), then you could use a union.

```
SELECT column names FROM table1 WHERE call_status='Open'
UNION ALL
SELECT column names FROM table2 WHERE call_status='Open'
```

You can use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to get unique rows, as pointed out by Fionnuala.

Comment: Just a note, UNION for unique rows, UNION ALL for faster, non-unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use join query.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Call_Status=table2.Call_Status and table1.Call_Status='Open' ;
```

Comment: Its not working though. its showing an error like : Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The specified field 'Call_Date' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: You will have to prefix the table name: Select table1.Call_Status, table2.Call_Status From ...

Comment: If you can provide your table structure. I can provide better solution .

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables by the attribute call_status like below.

`SELECT (Your column names)`
       `FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2`
         `ON Table1.call_status='open' and Table2.call_status='open';`

Comment: Its not working though. its showing an error like : Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The specified field 'Call_Date' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: i think its because both tables contain multiple columns having same name

Comment: i think there will be a problem in your database other than this